# Pyspark not printing any data from kafka stream, not failing either

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, databricks, spark-structured-streaming

I am new to spark and kafka. Using a kafka server created from a free Kafka server provider(Cloudkarafka) to consume data from. On running the pyspark code(on databricks) to consume stream data, the stream just keeps initializing, and doesn't fetch anything. Neither it fails, nor stops execution, just keeps showing status as "Stream Initializing".

The code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

kafkaServer="<server>"

editsDF=(spark.readStream
        .format("kafka")
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers",kafkaServer)
        .option("sasl.username","<username>")
        .option("sasl.password","<password>")
        .option("group.id", "%s-consumer" % "<username>")
        .option("session.timeout.ms", 6000)
        .option("default.topic.config", {"auto.offset.reset": "smallest"})
        .option('security.protocol', 'SASL_SSL')
        .option('sasl.mechanisms', 'SCRAM-SHA-256')
        .option("subscribe","<topic>")
        .option("startingOffsets","latest")
        .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger",1000)
        .load()
        .select(col("value").cast("STRING"))
        )


query = editsDF \
    .writeStream \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .format("console") \
    .start()
```

[The status in databricks while running the code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b59eH.png)

Please let me know if I am missing anything. Thanks in advance.

Note: I had made sure that kafka server is able to produce messages and was able to consume it in a python program. But not working in pyspark. Also, the size of data is very small, so no issues due to performance.

EDIT:This suggested function display() is still not printing any data for this Kafka server in question, however it is working fine when I tried with completely another Kafka server. I think this is because this kafka server(which is having issue) is using SASL-SCRAM authentication, so maybe it needs to be configured bit differently. Please provide any details/links/sample if you have on connecting SASL Kafka from Pyspark. Thanks!

Comment: do you put any data into Kafka topic after you started?

Comment: Shouldn't `query.awaitTermination()` be added to not terminate your main process

Comment: @AlexOtt          yeah, i have been sending data into Kafka topic manually, whenever I run the code.

Comment: @1pluszara                     I added query.awaitTermination(), but the code just keeps running. Still not printing anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print out Structured Stream in Console format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53231997/how-to-print-out-structured-stream-in-console-format/67003316#67003316)

Answer (score 1):

When you're using the `console` sink, then it prints data to the standard output (see the [Spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#output-sinks)), so you need to check the driver logs in the Cluster UI for produced data.

To see the data in the Databricks notebook itself, you need to use the `display` function that supports display of data from structured stream (see the [Databricks docs](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/visualizations/index.html#display-function-1)).  So instead of

```py
query = editsDF \
    .writeStream \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .format("console") \
    .start()
```

you just need to write:

```py
display(editsDF)
```

You can also pass additional options to this function, such as, `checkpointLocation`, `trigger`, etc. - check the docs that I linked above.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Earlier I didn't know that we can use display() to see streaming data. However, the issue seems to be different. This display() is still not printing any data for this Kafka server in question, however it is working fine when I tried with completely another Kafka server. I think this is because the kafka server(which is having issue) is using SASL authentication, so maybe it needs to be configured bit differently. Please provide any details/links if you have on connecting SASL Kafka from Pyspark. Thanks!

Comment: if you had the problem with authentication, then the operation would fail - if it works, then it's something else, like, you're sending to the wrong topic or some other reason