# Spark Streaming display (streaming) not working

Tags: file, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, spark-streaming

I follow this [example](https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/using-mllib-with-structured-streaming.html) to simulate streaming in Spark from a source file. At the end of the example, a function named **display** is used  which is **supported only** in **databricks**. I run my code in **Jupyter** notebook. What is the alternative in Jupyter to get the same output obtained from **display** function?

[screenshoot_of_the_Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAOPe.png)

Update_1:
The code:

```
 # Source
sourceStream=spark.readStream.format("csv").\
option("header",True).\
schema(schema).option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace",True).\
option("mode","dropMalformed").\
option("maxFilesPerTrigger",1).load("D:/PHD Project/Paper_3/Tutorials/HeartTest_1/").\
withColumnRenamed("output","label")

#stream test data to the ML model
streamingHeart=pModel.transform(sourceStream).select('label')
```

I do the following:

```
streamingHeart.writeStream.outputMode("append").\
format("csv").option("path", "D:/PHD \
Project/Paper_3/Tutorials/sa1/").option("checkpointLocation",\ 
"checkpoint/filesink_checkpoint").start()\
```

The problem is that the generated files (output files) are empty. What might be the reason behind that?

Comment: Perfect answer you can refer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67651610/pyspark-not-printing-any-data-from-kafka-stream-not-failing-either

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53231997/how-to-print-out-structured-stream-in-console-format

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing the checkpoint, as follow.

```
Project/Paper_3/Tutorials/sa1/").option("checkpointLocation",\ 
"checkpoint/filesink_checkpoint_1")
```